# Unable to connect app in Worklight Mobile Test Workbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I am running Worklight 6.1.0.1.  I have a simple helloworld app.  I can run the app on the android emulator.  I instrument and create a Mobile Test Workbench project.  I can connect the MTW client to eclipse and see the HW app.  When I try to record a test, I get this error after the splash screen:

```
Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
```

Logcat shows the cordova loadUrlNow() but not much else. The app connects when I run it straight on the emulator, so its a bit perplexing.

Comment: When you say "a simple helloworld app", what does "simple" mean?

Comment: Basically the sample app.  After repeated attempts of doing this:          1. delete everything in the Test Perspective

Comment: After repeated attempts of doing this: 1. delete everything in the Test Perspective  2. re exporting the apk  3. Run As -> Test with IBM Mobile Test Workbench   4. recreating the MTW project......I have this app working.  I moved onto my real app and I have the same problem, so I do not have a repeatable process.

Answer (score 0):

One of the attempts spit out this message:  E/CordovaWebView(800): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!

(Usually logcat was was just full of  "RMoTIDLE: Thread[main,5,main] main loop queue is idle"  and  "Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"  and I didn't see the timeout.)

So just adding "super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);"  to the main java class fixed this problem.

(Obviously the emulator is not the best place to be test driving this feature)